# Is it possible to store QueryCursor on Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know whether we can store query cursors on Firestore or not. If so then how can we retrieve it back as a DocumentSnapshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't heard of any QueryCursor class so far, but in Firestore you can **only** [store supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

**Edit:**

> But when I do so, I get errors in deserializing the object.

That's normal behavior since that type of object is not supported. So it cannot be deserialized.

> And for where to start at I want to store the last document snapshot on the Firestore database and retrieve it later for paginating.

Most likely you should consider storing that data in a data structure called [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) and use it any time you need it. This persists application restarts.

Comment: Actually I am paginating my data with query cursor. And for where to start at i want to store the last document snapshot on the firestore database and retrieve it later for paginating. As i don't want the previous documents to be included. I could have stored the document id for it. But the documents may get deleted the next time i use it. So i thought that query cursors is the way to go. But when i do so, i get error in deserializing the object.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it ok now?

Comment: What if the user logs into a new device and i need the documentSnapshot there?

Comment: In that case, SharedPreferences won't help. So if you want to continue the pagination process on different devices, then the single option that you have is to store the ID in the database (Firestore).

Comment: Ok, last question. Is it possible anyway through FirestoreCloudFunctions?

Comment: No, Cloud Functions lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features. So that won't help.

Comment: Alright then. Thanks @Alex_Mamo.

Comment: You're very welcome, Cyborg.